# Construct a JArray with only strings values without a key in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, sendgrid

I would highly appreciate if someone helped me out with constructing a JArray in C# by only using values and no key. Here is an example of the what I want:

```
{[
  "ZGVyZWtAcG9zc2tpLmNvbQ==",
  "YW5kcmVAbGltYWcubmV0",
  "YW5keUBiYW9iYW9tYWlsLmNvbQ==",
  "dGVzdEBraW5ub3YuY29t",
  "c2hhaG5hd2F6LmFsYW0xM0Bob3RtYWlsLmNvbQ==",
  "YnJlYW5uQGVtYWlsLmNvbQ=="
]}
```

Here is the code I wrote for it but I am getting an exception because when I declare JObject, it requires me to have a key and a value, but i only need the value as I am sending this array as a parameter to an API, and they need it in a specific format.

Here is my code that causes the issue:

```
var recipients = new JArray();
foreach (var c in retrievedContacts.recipients)
{
    var jsonObject = new JObject();
    jsonObject.Add(c.id);
    recipients.Add(jsonObject);
}
dynamic addToListResponse = await sg.client.contactdb.lists._(listJson.lists[0].id).recipients.post(requestBody: recipients);
```

The last line sends a post request to SendGrid. Here the list id is valid, everything is ok except for adding json object in the loop. Please Help!

Comment: I answered your question about how to construct a `JArray`, then realized your JSON is invalid.  Upload it to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see an error.  Your outer container is has braces - `{` and then `}` -- but does not consist of name/value pairs.  It only has a single value, which is an array.  Are you sure this is what you want?  Or do you want somethng like `{"requestBody": [..]}`

Answer (score 1):

To create a [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) with specified values, you can use [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to convert your `c.id` to a `JToken`, then [construct](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_2.htm) your `JArray` as follows:

```
var recipients = new JArray(retrievedContacts.recipients.Select(c => JToken.FromObject(c.id)));
```

In particular, this works if `id` is a byte array.  In this case Json.Net will convert it to a base64 string.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/brYEKR).

If `c.id` is *already* a string (in your question, you don't specify its type), you can skip the call to `FromObject()` and add it as-is without serialization:

```
var recipients = new JArray(retrievedContacts.recipients.Select(c => c.id));
```